# Propagate DataContext to Dependency Property from ContentControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, contentcontrol

I have a styled ContentControl with a DependencyProperty which, among others, has a DataTemplate property (StatusTemplate) that I have to assign to a DataTemplate I got in resources (StatusTemplate1).

The ContentControl is shown and the 'Binding:: ' text from StatusTemplate1 is also displayed, but the binding is empty. 
If I'm not mistaken, ContentControl doesn't propagate its DataContext to their Content, so the question is: is there any workaround I could use in order StatusTemplate1 receives the DataContext ? I'd prefer to use XAML only for this, but I've got no problem if code-behind is the way to go.

EDIT: the problem here is how to propagate the DataContext to the dependency property StatusTemplate. I changed the question title as it seems to be misleading.

The DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StatusTemplate1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Binding:: " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl Style="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToStyleConverter}}" 
    dp1:AddOn.StatusTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate1}">
</ContentControl>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to simplify the whole construct in order to find the culprit: What is displayed when you just put this in your xaml?:
`<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate1}" Content="{Binding Path=Status}"/>`

Comment: Thanks Martin. Doing what you suggested works ok for the ContentControl itself. The problem is to propagate the binding to the dependency property template.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "propagate a binding to the DP template". Maybe you should reveal more of the code that is involved in setting the `ContentTemplate` on the `ContentControl`. Otherwise this is just "fishing in muddy waters".

Comment: You're right. I'm working on it.

Comment: While working on a stripped down version to show I decided to remove the feature using the dependency property as I don't think it's worth the trouble. I can't make it show the problem I was into and I don't think it's how it has to be done either. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very similar scenario, and if I recall correctly,

```
Content="{Binding}"
```

As an attribute of the contentcontrol actually works.

Comment: Thanks Boluc. I've tried it, but what I need is binding the dependency property StatusTemplate. Doing what you suggested works ok, but not for the dependency property.